# Django Rest Framework Auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a web application project that uses Django rest framework for its backend and angular 2 for the front end, I want to know if it's recommended to use Django User model for the authentification of my login form (I mean save all user in Django admin), or should I make another User model specifically for the app ?

P.S: The application will be using the JWT token for authentification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project):

> If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises:

It is highly recommended that you create the Custom User Model instead of going with default User model provided by django unless you are very sure that you wont need any changes in the functionalities of the user model.

You can also extend the User model using OneToOneRelationship if all you wanted is adding extra fields.

Even if you add custom user model, it can still be added and viewed in Django Admin.